# Android XML Editor Error

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]
When I'm   opening Eclipse this error is shown on screen and donot show any project

Comment: do u recently changed your workspace or deleted/closed any project

Comment: no , i donot change any thing, last friday i shut down my pc proprly, now i on my pc this error shown to me

Comment: is there all your project in workspace.If yes change your workspace into new one, after restart eclipse change to old .It may work.Otherwise you want to import all your project into new workspace

Comment: there is no project, now i am importing my projects into new workspace